# Unknown plant, can anybody identify this plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Location: Western Germany 
Can anybody identify this plant from Germany ?
[image: plant from Germany]

[image: plant another view]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *Phytolacca esculenta*, Asian pokeweed. Because the flower stalks (berry) are standing upright, and not hanging. The berries are also closer together compared to *P. americana*.

Despite the name 'esculenta', this plant is also poisonous.

[image: picture from wikipedia commons]
https://m.wikidata.org/wiki/Q17244662

Comment: Ah yes right, oversaw this fact. Thank you very much RHA!!!

Comment: @nkell13s if you think this answer is better, consider accepting this answer (the check sign).

Comment: And just FTR, it becomes a pest quite easily. Seeds are dispersed by birds and other animals. It has tubers which can grow quite large, and regrowth can occur even from parts of the tuber from my experience.

Answer (score 5):

### Looks like Phytolacca americana

Better known as pokeweed, [*Phytopacca americana*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana) is native to the western US but naturalized in Germany and other European countries. The “berries” are quite distinct.

Comment: And it is quite poisonous!  The unique color to the berry pigment is due to a class of compounds called betalains, specifically betacyanins.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you very much ! Pretty interesting plant though

Comment: I think you are right this is Phytopacca, but it is another species. See my answer below.

Comment: @RHA oooh, good call - you should get the check